# How to store image eigenvalue in mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, json, image-processing

I work in image match these days, I need to store image color eigenvalue in the mysql for query image match. I use java to do that.

The eigenvalue should store in structure like key-value(HSV color - Number of that color), such like:

`"257094":0.067,"257350":0.063,"258374":0.055,"256070":0.039,"257606":0.038,"258886":0.037...`

[image]

I use Map store it, transform it to `json` string and store it in the mysql for field type `longtext`. So when a query comes, I pick up the json string from database and transform it to map then compare.

But My method's performance is too low, is it that any better method can deal with it?

Comment: Are you scanning the whole table to retrieve each of your stored images' eigen-values to test each one at a time?

Comment: A query for scanning 5000 images, almost 3 or 4 minutes

Comment: depending on how big those serialized histograms are, and how slow your network is, and how powerful is your hardware.. it could be; can you cache locally?

Comment: I want to know it's the normal method to use json to transform histogram data to string and then store to the database?

Comment: It depends on how you want to use the histogram data. If you store the serialized histogram data in the database you can't query against it (you have to pull it down and deserialize to test). It seems like in your case it's not the right approach. How do you compare the histogram data? I'm assuming you're not doing exact matching..

Comment: I am now store serialized histogram data in the database, when query against it, I deserialize the data and compare with the query histogram data (query image directly extract the histogram data), after comparison return the similarity.